# Как передать изображение из класса mat (OpenCV) в класс Image (JavaFX)?

Tags: opencv, java, javafx

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать изображение из класса mat (OpenCV) в класс Image (JavaFX)?

P.S.

```
Image - import javafx.scene.image.Image;
```